What would be a better way to deal with a ifstreams failed state in this code?
I was reading Bjarne Stroustrup's "Principle and Practice using C++". Chapter 10.6 is about error handling of iostreams. He highlights that you should always try to recover from a fail() state if you can, while a bad() state is generally a lost cause.
I then tried to follow this principle when making a function which sums integers separated by whitespaces in some file:
int sum_integers(std::ifstream& is, int sum = 0)
{
    if (!is) throw std::invalid_argument("Ifstream given was already in not good state");
    is.exceptions(std::ios_base::badbit); // will throw error if state becomes bad
        
    for (int num; is >> num; )
    {
        sum += num;
    }
        
    if (is.eof()) 
    {
        is.clear();
    }
    else // means state is fail()
    {
        is.clear();
        char c; is >> c;
        std::cerr << "Unvalid character '" << c << "' was encountered\n";
        is.clear(std::ios_base::failbit); 
    }
    return sum;
}

So, the caller could, for example, deal with/ignore bad data in the following way:
int main()
{
    {
        std::string filename = "exer1_data.txt";
        std::ifstream is{filename};
            
        try
        {
            int sum = sum_integers(is);
            while (is.fail())
            {
                is.clear();
                sum = sum_integers(is, sum);
            }
            std::cout << sum << std::endl;
        }
        catch(const std::invalid_argument& e)
        {
            std::cerr << e.what() << '\n';
        }
    }
}

So, if exer1_data.txt contained the following:
1 2 3 a 5

The result would still be 11.
Even though this code works, it seems a little clumsy. What are some recommended improvements to the code, and some better techniques for dealing with the fail() state?

OT: Don't pass references to specific streams (like std::ifstream), but rather the generic stream (i.e. std::istream). That way your functions could work with any input stream, like for example std::cin or a std::istringstream.

As for input and input validation, my recommendation is to always read input as text, preferably whole lines with std::getline. Then use e.g. std::stoi to convert the string to an int value, with validation.

Also, don't clear the status on EOF. That means you could attempt to read from the input again, even though it might not be possible.

A istream (mostly) enters a fail() state due to an input mismatch (e.g. reading an int and encountering a 'z'). Most such failures may be avoided by reading the stream as a sequence of characters or of strings (e.g. set::getline()), parsing, and returning an error code (not throwing) on bad input (a program can/should usually detect and deal gracefully with bad input). A bad() state means compromised function of the stream itself (e.g. a hardware failure affecting ability to read a file from drive), which is harder to recover from, so throwing an exception is often more appropriate.

Your while (is.fail()) loop in main() won't work as sum_integers() is clearing the failure state before exiting. All you are really doing is summing valid integers and ignoring non-integer characters. If that is what you really want then you should handle that inside of sum_integers() itself.
